# Binding DropDownList with array of DataRow

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu, datarow

I am binding the `DropDownList` with `DataRow` but it is throwing an exception:

> DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with the name 'CourseEligiblility'.

Code:

```
DataRow[] dRow = dt.Select("CourseID=" + ddlCourse.SelectedValue);
ddlBeStream.DataTextField = "CourseEligiblility";
ddlBeStream.DataValueField = "ID";
ddlBeStream.DataSource = dRow;
ddlBeStream.DataBind();
```

Comment: Is data being returned from the dt.Select function?

Answer (score 6):

Just use the function that copies DataRow Array to a new DataTable and returns it.

```
//  .
//  .
//  .
ddlBeStream.DataSource = dRow.CopyToDataTable;
ddlBeStream.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 4):

Take DataView and filter it by field

for example.

```
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = "colums=1";
DropDownList1.DataSource = dv;
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "colName";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "colID";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `using ddlBeStream.DataBind();`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made a mistake writing the name of the field. Try the following:

```
ddlBeStream.DataTextField = "CourseEligibility";
```

Comment: @Akram Shahda: no field name is right . if i directly bind dropdownlist from datatable, it doesn't show any error.

Comment: @Mohan: Please try to double check it. Try to remove the second _L_ from the field name.

Comment: this is same as database field name.

Comment: @Akram: problem is as it was.. no solution yet.

Comment: @AkramShahda let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/960/discussion-between-mohan-and-akram-shahda)

Answer (score 0):

For people still using older versions of ASP.net:

```
DataRow[] dRow = dt.Select("CourseID=" + ddlCourse.SelectedValue);
//Copy Datatable and import found rows
System.Data.DataTable dt_Temp = dt.Clone();    
foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in drRow) { dt_Temp.ImportRow(dr); }

ddlBeStream.DataTextField = "CourseEligiblility";
ddlBeStream.DataValueField = "ID";
//Use new DataTable
ddlBeStream.DataSource = dt_Temp;
ddlBeStream.DataBind();
```